# Google map not now showing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

My website was working quite happily up until yesterday and I've got no idea why.

I've not changed anything on the coding which is rather annoying.

I know the GMAP2 API has been stopped this month, but as far as I can work out my code is API3.

Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <Head> 
        <title>Fishtrends | Tightlines</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0>
        <link href = "css/css/bootstrap.css" rel = "Stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet" type='text/css'>
        <link href = "css/css/style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href = "css/fonts/fonta/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <script type="text/javascript" script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" script src="css/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.3&sensor=false"></script>

    <script>

    var marker;
    var infowindow;
    var map;
    var customIcons = {
    Bass:   {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png'
      },
    Cod: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      },
      Gurnard: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png'
      },
      Flatty: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png'
      },
      Mackerel: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_gray.png'
      },
      Whiting: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png'
      },
      Pollack: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png'
      },
      Wrasse: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png'
      },
      Pout: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_brown.png'
      },
      Blank: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
       },
      };
    function initialize() {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54.559322, -4.174804);
      var options = {
        zoom: 6,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), options);
      var html = "<table>" +
                 "<h4> <b>Lets add some fish!</b></h4>" +
                 "<tr><td>Fish Species:</td> <td><select id='fishspecies'>" +
                         "<option value='Bass' SELECTED>Bass</option>" +
                         "<option value='Cod'>Cod</option>" +
                         "<option value='Gurnard'>Gurnard</option>" +           
                         "<option value='Flatty'>Flatty</option>" +
                         "<option value='Mackeral'>Mackeral</option>" +
                         "<option value='Whiting'>Whiting</option>" +
                         "<option value='Pollack'>Pollack</option>" +
                         "<option value='Wrasse'>Wrasse</option>" +
                         "<option value='Pout'>Pout</option>" +
                 "<option value='Blank'>Blank</option>" +                            
                 "<tr><td>Catch Method:</td> <td><select id='catchmethod'>" +
                         "<option value='Beach' SELECTED>Beach</option>" +
                         "<option value='Boat'>Boat</option>" +
                         "<option value='Spinning'>Spinning</option>" +
                 "<option value='Pier'>Pier</option>" +

                 "<tr><td>Bait:</td> <td><select id='bait'>" +
                         "<option value='Lugworm' SELECTED>Lugworm</option>" +
                         "<option value='Mackerel'>Makerel</option>" +
                         "<option value='Ragworm' >Ragworm</option>" +
                         "<option value='Livebait'>Livebait</option>" +
                         "<option value='Squid'>Squid</option>" +
                         "<option value='Peeler'>Peeler</option>" +

                 "<tr><td>Size LB:</td> <td><input type='text' id='sizelb'/> </td> </tr>" +              

                 "<tr><td>Month Caught:</td> <td><select id='date'>" +
                         "<option value='January' SELECTED>January</option>" +
                         "<option value='February'>February</option>" +
                         "<option value='March'>March</option>" +           
                         "<option value='April'>April</option>" +
                         "<option value='May'>May</option>" +
                         "<option value='June'>June</option>" +
                         "<option value='July'>July</option>" +
                         "<option value='August'>August</option>" +
                         "<option value='September'>September</option>" +
                         "<option value='October'>October</option>" +
                         "<option value='November'>November</option>" +
                         "<option value='December'>December</option>" + 
                 "</select> </td></tr>" +

                 "<tr><td></td><td><input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' value='Save and Close' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>";


 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: html
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: event.latLng,
          map: map
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });


    });


      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
        savefishdata();
    }

    function savefishdata() {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
        downloadUrl("phpsqldom.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var fishname = markers[i].getAttribute("fishspecies");         
          var fishbait = markers[i].getAttribute("bait");
          var caughttime = markers[i].getAttribute("date");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + fishname + "</b> <br/>" + fishbait + caughttime;
          var icon = customIcons[fishname] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }
    function saveData() {
      var fishspecies = escape(document.getElementById("fishspecies").value);

      var catchmethod = escape(document.getElementById("catchmethod").value);
      var bait = document.getElementById("bait").value;

      var sizelb = document.getElementById("sizelb").value;
      var date = document.getElementById("date").value;

      var latlng = marker.getPosition();              
     var url = "phpsqlinfo_addrow.php?fishspecies=" + fishspecies + "&catchmethod=" + catchmethod + "&bait=" + bait + "&date=" + date + "&lat=" + latlng.lat() + "&lng=" + latlng.lng() + "&sizelb=" + sizelb ;
      downloadUrl(url, function(data, responseCode) {
        if (responseCode == 200 && data.responseText.length <= 1) {
          infowindow.close();

        }
      });
    }
    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class = "navbar navbar-main navbar-static-top">
            <div class= "container">
                <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand"><b>Fishtrends</b> - Social Fish trending</a>
                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse"
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class = "icon-bar"></span>
                </button>


                <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class = "active"><a href ="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Home</a></li>
                        <li class = "dropdown">
                            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>
                            Profile<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class = "dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href = "#">My Details</a></li>
                                <li><a href = "/edit_account.php">Change Password</a></li>
                            </ul> 
                        <li><a href ="/logout.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>               
                                </div>  
    </div>

        <div class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom">

                <div class = "container">
                    <p class = "navbar-text pull-left">Copyright Fishtrends - 2013 <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-copyright-mark"></i></p>
                    <a href = "http://www.twitter.com/fishtrends" class = "navbar-btn btn-primary btn pull-right"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-1x"></i> Follow Us</a>
                    <p class = "navbar-text pull-right"><a href ="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i> About Us</a></p>
                </div>

        </div>

        </div>


    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-3" style=padding-right:0px > 
                    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/fishtrends" data-widget-id="400362818177748992">Tweets by @fishtrends</a>
                    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>



                    <h4><b>Fish types</b></h4>
                    <ul class="fishlist-group">
                         <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png"> Bass</li>
                         <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png"> Cod</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_orange.png"> Gurnard</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_green.png"> Flatfish</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_gray.png"> Mackerel</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_white.png"> Whiting</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_black.png"> Pollack</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_purple.png"> Wrasse</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_brown.png"> Pout</li>
                        <li class="fishlist-group-item">
                            <img src="http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png"> Blank!</li>

                    </ul>



                </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-9">
                      <div id="map-canvas">
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>      


    </body>
```

Comment: What have you tried to fix it? Any clues about what did happen to your site?

Comment: The trailing comma at the end of the last item in your customIcons struct here will cause errors in IE: `Blank: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
       },`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "width" and "height" for div id "map-canvas" and map will appear.

```
<style>
  #map_canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: What a donut I am...I'd edited my production Style.css by mistake thinking it was Staging.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link. http://jsfiddle.net/y829C/1/

```
var mapOptions = {
                     center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude),
                      zoom: 8,
                     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

                };
```